# How to create matrix from table in .txt file

Tags: python

I need to create a matrix from a text file.
the "delimiter" are not constant, sometimes it is 5 spaces and sometimes more or less.
dose any one know how to do it?

I just have the lines separated, by using this code:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

# getting file loction and name from user:
file_path = 'file_path'
file = open(file_path) # open the file
lines = file.readlines()
```

[image]

I expect the output of matrix with 5 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

try following:

```py
import pandas as pd

file_path = 'file_path'

lines = pd.read_csv(file_path, sep=r'\s+')
```

Comment: if I want to skip the 2 first lines what should I do?

Comment: @Benzy If you skip the first line, you won't be able to use the last.

Comment: if the number of spaces is not constant, how can I separate each row?

Comment: `sep=r'\s+'` is taking non-consistent amount of spaces already... if the amount of spaces were consistent you should've done `sep=" "`